# Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Ef core 5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-forms-core

I using CleanArchitecture solution. I have Data layer where ApplicationDbContext and UnitOfWork are located :

```
namespace Portal.Data.MyDbContexts
{
    internal class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(BaseEntity).Assembly);
        }


        // **********
        public DbSet<WebsiteMonitoredCategory> WebsiteMonitoredCategories { get; set; }
        // **********


        
    }
```

unitofwork:

```
public abstract class BaseUnitOfWork : object, IBaseUnitOfWork
    {
        //public UnitOfWork() : base()
        //{
        //}

        public BaseUnitOfWork(Options options) : base()
        {
            Options = options;
        }

        // **********
        protected Options Options { get; set; }
        // **********

        // **********
        // **********
        // **********
        private ApplicationDbContext _databaseContext;
        // **********

        // **********
        /// <summary>
        /// Lazy Loading = Lazy Initialization
        /// </summary>
        internal ApplicationDbContext DatabaseContext
        {
            get
            {
                if (_databaseContext == null)
                {
                    var optionsBuilder =
                        new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();

                    switch (Options.Provider)
                    {
                        case Provider.SqlServer:
                            {
                                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer
                                    (connectionString: Options.ConnectionString);

                                break;
                            }

                        case Provider.MySql:
                            {
                                //optionsBuilder.UseMySql
                                //  (connectionString: Options.ConnectionString);

                                break;
                            }

                        case Provider.Oracle:
                            {
                                //optionsBuilder.UseOracle
                                //  (connectionString: Options.ConnectionString);

                                break;
                            }

                        case Provider.PostgreSQL:
                            {
                                //optionsBuilder.UsePostgreSQL
                                //  (connectionString: Options.ConnectionString);

                                break;
                            }

                        case Provider.InMemory:
                            {
                                optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Temp");

                                break;
                            }

                        default:
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                    }

                    _databaseContext =
                        new ApplicationDbContext(options: optionsBuilder.Options);
                }

                return _databaseContext;
            }
        }
```

and I have IoC Layer too for dependency injection to presentation layer:

```
public class DependencyContainer
    {
        public static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services,IConfiguration configuration)
        {

            
            //DataLayer
            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(_ =>
            {
                Options options =
                    new Options
                    {
                        Provider =
                            (Provider)System.Convert.ToInt32(configuration.GetSection(key: "DatabaseProvider").Value),

                    

                        ConnectionString =
                            configuration.GetSection(key: "ConnectionStrings").GetSection(key: "MyConnectionString").Value,
                    };

                return new UnitOfWork(options: options);
            });


        }
    }
```

and finally I Have an Windows Forms application Net 5.0 (All Projects are Net5.0)

```
namespace Portal.Desktop
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var services = ConfigureServices();

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            
        

            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
            RegisterServices(services, Configuration);
        }

        public static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            DependencyContainer.RegisterServices(services, configuration);
        }

        public static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            //services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(_ =>
            //{
            //  Options options =
            //      new Options
            //      {
            //          Provider =
            //              (Provider)System.Convert.ToInt32(Configuration.GetSection(key: "DatabaseProvider").Value),

            //          //using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
            //          //ConnectionString =
            //          //  Configuration.GetConnectionString().GetSection(key: "MyConnectionString").Value,

            //          ConnectionString =
            //              Configuration.GetSection(key: "ConnectionStrings").GetSection(key: "MyConnectionString").Value,
            //      };

            //  return new Portal.Data.UoW.UnitOfWork(options: options);
            //});


            ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

I usage Ef core 5.0 , windows forms is set as startup project and package  manager console  set to Protal.Data (dbcontext and unitofwork in there)
but when i run *Add-Migration inti* in PMC get me an error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the
> different patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

installed  this packages in data layer:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.7">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.7">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I don't know why, get me the error.

-----UPDATE----

I follow the https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 and added *ApplicationDbContextFactory.cs* to Portal.Desktop (windows forms Net5.0) project:

```
namespace Portal.Desktop
{
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory:IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = Program.Configuration.GetSection(key: "ConnectionStrings").GetSection(key: "MyConnectionString").Value;
            var provider = Program.Configuration.GetSection(key: "DatabaseProvider").Value;
            var optionsBuilder =
                new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var options =
                new Options
                {
                    Provider =
                        (Provider)System.Convert.ToInt32(provider),

                    //using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
                    //ConnectionString =
                    //  Configuration.GetConnectionString().GetSection(key: "MyConnectionString").Value,

                    ConnectionString = connectionString,
                };
            switch (options.Provider)
            {
                case Provider.SqlServer:
                {
                    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer
                        (connectionString: options.ConnectionString);

                    break;
                }

                case Provider.MySql:
                {
                    //optionsBuilder.UseMySql
                    //  (connectionString: Options.ConnectionString);

                    break;
                }

                case Provider.Oracle:
                {
                    //optionsBuilder.UseOracle
                    //  (connectionString: Options.ConnectionString);

                    break;
                }

                case Provider.PostgreSQL:
                {
                    //optionsBuilder.UsePostgreSQL
                    //  (connectionString: Options.ConnectionString);

                    break;
                }

                case Provider.InMemory:
                {
                    optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Temp");

                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return 
                new ApplicationDbContext(options: optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

When I want add a migration ef core throw *Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.* exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation.  ---> System.NullReferenceException:
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
> Portal.Desktop.ApplicationDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(String[]
> args) in C:\Users\Arman
> Es\source\repos\Spider\Portal.Desktop\ApplicationDbContextFactory.cs:line
> 20    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[]
> parameters)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContextFromFactory(Type
> factory, Type contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_2.b__9()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: What is selected as default (in PMC) and start up projects?

Comment: Did you visit the link given in the error message? It tells you what to do.

Comment: @GuruStron Portal.Data (Data Layer)

Comment: @DavidG I did not have this problem in previous projects .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, I found my answers in this article https://snede.net/you-dont-need-a-idesigntimedbcontextfactory/

Create *ApplicationDbContextFactory* in Portal.Data project:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Portal.Domain.Tools;
using Portal.Domain.Tools.Enums;

namespace Portal.Data.MyDbContexts
{
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory:IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            var optionsBuilder =
                new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var options =
                new Options
                {
                    Provider =
                        (Provider)System.Convert.ToInt32(Configuration.GetSection(key: "DatabaseProvider").Value),
                    ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection(key: "ConnectionStrings").GetSection(key: "MyConnectionString").Value
                };

            switch (options.Provider)
            {
                case Provider.SqlServer:
                {
                    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer
                        (connectionString: options.ConnectionString);

                    break;
                }

                case Provider.MySql:
                {
                    //optionsBuilder.UseMySql
                    //  (connectionString: Options.ConnectionString);

                    break;
                }

                case Provider.Oracle:
                {
                    //optionsBuilder.UseOracle
                    //  (connectionString: Options.ConnectionString);

                    break;
                }

                case Provider.PostgreSQL:
                {
                    //optionsBuilder.UsePostgreSQL
                    //  (connectionString: Options.ConnectionString);

                    break;
                }

                case Provider.InMemory:
                {
                    optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Temp");

                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return 
                new ApplicationDbContext(options: optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json** still in Portal.Desktop project:

```
namespace Portal.Desktop
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public  static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var services = ConfigureServices();

            RegisterServices(services, Configuration);


            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
            
        }

        public static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            DependencyContainer.RegisterServices(services, configuration);
        }

        public static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            

            ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally *IoC* project is:

```
namespace Portal.IoC
{
    public class DependencyContainer
    {
        public static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services,IConfiguration configuration)
        {

            //DataLayer
            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(_ =>
            {
                var options =
                    new Options
                    {
                        Provider =
                            (Provider)System.Convert.ToInt32(configuration.GetSection(key: "DatabaseProvider").Value),
                        ConnectionString =
                            configuration.GetSection(key: "ConnectionStrings").GetSection(key: "MyConnectionString").Value,
                    };

                return new UnitOfWork(options: options);
            });

        


        }
    }
}
```